# "The project is targeting API Level 'android-33', which is not installed" BUT, I have installed it

Tags: android, xamarin, sdk

I opened a new project, a Basic Android App(Android, Gradle) in Visual Studio 2022 Community. Upon creating the project, I get the warning in the title.

I tried to install, uninstall, re-install, update and whatnot, but the warning still doesn't go.
I tried it through Visual Studio's SDK manager, through Android Studio's SDK manager to see if that would help and even tried to manually install the required SDK's. however, the warning still persists. Please advice. [Warning in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eezfm.jpg)   [SDK Platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xvv4.jpg)   [SDK Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rekvk.jpg)

Comment: `I get the warning in the title.`  Please do never refer to the title of a post to post your info. Just put all info in your post. Lesson 1.

Comment: It probably gives you that error because you are trying to run Java code in a C# IDE

Answer (score 0):

As FreakyAli said that Visual Studio can not run Java code directly: [Warning in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eezfm.jpg). However, you can creat an [Android App project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCc78.png) via [Xamarin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65LWN.png) and then migrate the code into it:

```cs
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.Text = "Hello World!";

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        //SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        SetContentView(tv);

   }
   
}
```

Here is the [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbh9R.png). For more info you can refer to the doc: [Xamarin Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/).